# Evenly fill a div with an input and button

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div with two inputs inside. One text box and one button. I would like to set the div to be a certain width (say 30em) and have the text box fill 80% of it and the button the other 20%. The inputs should be side by side. The div is centered in the page.

```
<div class="container">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Some text">
  <input class="button" type="submit">
</div>
```

I have this scss so far

```
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30em;
  .input {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .button {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

So far the text box takes up 80% but floats in the middle and the button under it. How can I line them up side by side to fill the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those elements are inline by default, so the white space between them is preserved, which makes their overall width 20% + 80% + [a space], which is > 100%.

You can...

- remove the white space between them
- use `display: flex` on the parent
- float the inputs.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.input {
  width: 80%;
}

.button {
  width: 20%;
}

.float {
  overflow: auto;
}

.float input {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Some text"><input class="button" type="submit">
</div>

<div class="container flex">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Some text">
  <input class="button" type="submit">
</div>

<div class="container float">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Some text">
  <input class="button" type="submit">
</div>
```